# Why 9600 data rate is used over other rates for Serial.begin()?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

I am working on Arduino and for communication purpose with the computer `Serial.begin()` function is being used. Now since there is a range of data rates from 300...115200.
Majority uses 9600!
Why is it so? What is its significance

Answer (score 4):

During previous millenium 9600 bauds has been a standard for some devices.

Currently this speed is enough for most cases, so they stick to it; many devices use 9600 baud as a default.

Personally I use serial for debugging most often. At 9600 baud, it can print more than 10 lines per second, that is more than I can read.

Yet you can keep in mind that the buffer is limited to 64 char and when it is full, arduino will block a `serial.write` instruction until there is enough space in buffer. That is why you encounter some slowdown with slow baud rates.

On the other sides you will burden the MCU with speed of 0.5M on hardware serial. And with software serial you may see an impact much sooner.

Personally I had some trouble with chinese nano that used CH340 USB/Serial; python communication to arduino with pyserial was unreliable at speed over 9600 bauds.

Answer (score 3):

Many devices use 9600 or 19200 baud, and I guess that people just copy over values without thinking about them, thereby continuing the practice even if it is no longer necessary.

That said, the [maximum length of a serial cable](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/187633/max-serial-cable-length) depends on the baud rate you choose. Higher baud rates require shorter cables. So if you don't need the higher rate, just stay with a low one like 9600.

Comment: The "serial cable lenght" on an Arduino with USB connection is only between the MCU and the USB-UART chip.

Comment: @gre_gor: the Arduino also has TX and RX pins that provide a "real" RS232 interface (albeit with TTL voltage levels). If you use these pins, which is not uncommon, and connect a cable to them, you have to take the cable length into account. But yes, if you use the USB cable, then you can use any speed you want, but are limitted by the maximum length allowed by USB instead :)

Comment: In case of PC-Arduino communication (like the OP is asking about), I doubt the cable length is taken into account in most cases. Even if an Arduino doesn't have an USB interface, the wires to the adapter will be short. As you said, I think it's mostly just about copy pasting the code, starting with the official docs and examples.